# How to implement a type converter from string to enum of the type bit-fields

Tags: wpf, xaml, bit-fields

I have an enum as:

C#

```
[Flags] 
public enum FieldStyle
{

    FS_ShadeWords = 0x00000001,
    FS_WithWords = 0x00000002,
    FS_WithLetters = 0x00000004,
    FS_MMDD_YYMM = 0x00000008,
    FS_T2WordsUnder = 0x00000010,
    FS_T2Style = 0x00000020,
    FS_AT1 = 0x00000040,
    FS_TP1Keying = 0x00000080,
    FS_T1KeyDate = 0x00000100,
    FS_H8Date =  0x00000200,
    FS_AT1Blob = 0x00000400,
    FS_ThickRight = 0x00000800,
    FS_ThickLeft = 0x00001000,
    FS_GreyBase = 0x00002000,
    FS_C017_Keying = 0x00004000,
    FS_CT23Date = 0x00008000,
    FS_TopEdge = 0x00010000,
    FS_DefaultDate = 0x00020000,
}
```

In a style I need to set a property as follow :

XAML:

```
<Setter Property="WhichFieldStyle" Value="FS_DefaultDate,FS_WithWords"/>
```

it is not accepted with XAML.

Anybody knows how to set a bit-field in XAML???

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: <Setter Property="WhichFieldStyle" value="FS_DefaultDate,FS_WithWords"/>

Comment: But how to implement the type converter that will convert this Value to the WhichFieldStyle, because now all I get is Could not be resolved.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I do not need a converter.

Comment: Please show your binding.  If you want to convert a byte based enum to byte the syntax is just (byte)enumDocRORW.RW

Answer (score 0):

i really don't know what goes wrong with your code, but this one works fine

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfAppCursorTest.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="uc">
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=WhichFieldStyle}" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```c#
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty WhichFieldStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("WhichFieldStyle", typeof(FieldStyle), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(FieldStyle)));

  public FieldStyle WhichFieldStyle {
    get { return (FieldStyle)this.GetValue(WhichFieldStyleProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(WhichFieldStyleProperty, value); }
  }

  public UserControl1() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppCursorTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:WpfAppCursorTest="clr-namespace:WpfAppCursorTest"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <WpfAppCursorTest:UserControl1 WhichFieldStyle="FS_DefaultDate,FS_WithWords,FS_TP1Keying" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

hope this helps